# Prove that $x\in P$, then there exists a neighborhood $O$ of $x$ such that $O\subset X$, $P$ is defined in a particular way.

Tags: general-topology, compactness

I'm reading Intro to Topology by Mendelson.

This is the first section on compact topological spaces.

The complete question is,

Let $\{U_\alpha\}_{\alpha\in I}$ be an open covering of $[0,1]$. Define a subset $P$ of $[0,1]$ as follows:

$x\in P$ if and only if there exists a finite subcollection of $\{U_\alpha\}_{\alpha\in I}$ that covers $[0,x]$, that is, $[0,x]\subset\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^n U_{\alpha_i}$.

Prove that if $x\in P$ then there exists a neighborhood $O$ of $x$ such that $O\subset P$.

I know that if we let $x\in P$, then for any $0\leq y\leq x$, $y\in P$ since, $[0,y]\subset[0,x]$. I also know that for every $x\in P$, $x\in U_{\alpha_i}$ for some $1\leq i\leq n$. What I'm thinking of showing is that one of the open sets $U_{\alpha_i}$ are in fact the neighborhood contained in $P$, yet I don't quite know how to go about doing this. I'm not even sure if this is the right approach.

Thanks for any hints or feedback!

Comment: Perhaps I am missing something, but using the fact that $[0,1]$ is compact we can deduce that $P=\mathbb{I}$. In this case $P$ will not contain an open subset of $\mathbb{R}$ that contains $1$

Comment: Yeah, the rest of problem goes on to ask that if $x\not\in P$ then $P$ is closed. Lastly, it then asks to show that $P=[0,1]$ and that therefore $[0,1]$ is compact. I'm in the section of the book which is right before the section that covers compact subsets of the real line.

Comment: Is this part of a proof of showing the compactness of $\mathbb{I}$

Comment: A remark about your last comment: the real line $\mathbb{R}$ is not compact

Comment: I'm not sure what $\mathbb{I}$ is.

Comment: I went ahead and edited that last part. I wrote in the title of the section.

Comment: $\mathbb{I}$ is the interval $[0,1]$

Comment: I see, yes the end result is to show the compactness of $[0,1]$.

Comment: OK does the proof begin by assuming that $\mathbb{I}$ is not compact, in an attempt to derive a contradiction ?

Comment: No it doesn't. I typed in the exact problem statement.

Comment: Hmmmm ${}{}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: Yup. ${}{}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: I'm a bit confused here; since [0,x] is closed in [0,1], it is automatically compact, for every x, as a closed subset of a compact set, isn't it?

Comment: Well, this problem is leading to show that the set $[0,1]$ is a compact set. That is, Mendelson has not yet proved as a theorem that $[0,1]$ is compact. He does in the following section to the one this problem was taken from.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose $x \in P$, then $[0,x] \subset \cup_{i=1}^n U_{\alpha_i}$. Hence $\exists j \in \{1,2\ldots, n\}$ such that $x \in U_{\alpha_j}$. Since $U_{\alpha_j}$ is open, $\exists \delta > 0$ such that $(x-\delta, x+\delta) \subset U_{\alpha_j}$. Now for any $y \in (x-\delta, x+\delta)$,
$$
[0,y] \subset [0,x+\delta) \subset \cup_{i=1}^n U_{\alpha_i}
$$
Hence, $y \in P$, and so $O = (x-\delta, x+\delta)$ is the open set you are looking for.

Comment: Question: The OP mentioned "Define a subset $P$ of $[0,1]$ as follows: ...." . I understood this as $P$ is defined to be $\{x\in [0,1] | [0,x]$ is covered by a finite subcover of $\{U_{\alpha}\}_{\alpha\in I}$  . Now in your solution, all elements $y$ of $(x-\delta,x+\delta)$ satisfy the property that  $[0,y]$ can be covered by a finite subcover of $\{U_{\alpha}\}_{\alpha\in I}$, but I don't see why all of them have to belong to $[0,1]$ ?

Comment: They don't. I was being sloppy. The ambient space is $[0,1]$, so one would have to take $O = (x-\delta,x+\delta)\cap [0,1]$.