# Prove that $x\not\in P$ then there exists a neighborhood $O$ of $x$ such that $O\cap P=\varnothing$. Certain definition on $P$.

Tags: general-topology, compactness

I'm reading Intro to Topology by Mendelson.

The problem statement is,

> Let $\{U_\alpha\}_{\alpha\in I}$ be an open covering of $[0,1]$. Define a subset $P$ of $[0,1]$ as follows:
>
> $x\in P$ if and only if there exists a finite subcollection of $\{U_\alpha\}_{\alpha\in I}$ that covers $[0,x]$, that is, $$[0,x]\subset\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^n U_{\alpha_i}.$$
>
> Prove that if $x\notin P$ then there exists a neighborhood $O$ of $x$ such that $O\cap P=\varnothing$.

This problem proceeds after this one posted [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/464116/prove-that-x-in-p-then-there-exists-a-neighborhood-o-of-x-such-that-o-su)

My attempt at the proof is,

Suppose $x\not\in P$. Then $x\in C(P)$ and since $P$ is open, $C(P)$ must be closed. Because $C(P)$ is closed, it contains the boundary of $P$. Thus, $x\in\text{Bdry}(P))$ or $x\in\text{Int}(C(P))$. If $x\in\text{Int}(C(P))$ then there exists an open set $O\subset\text{Int}(C(P))$ such that $O\cap P=\varnothing.$

I'm having trouble showing that the part with $x\in\text{Bdry}(P)$. I know that since its already shown earlier that $P$ is open and this proof will show that $P$ is closed that ultimately $\text{Bdry}(P)=\varnothing$, which means $x$ can't be in $\text{Bdry}(P)$.

Is there a way to avoid this process and show from the beginning that $x$ must lie in $\text{Int}(C(P))$? I'm also thinking of using the definition of $P$ to come up with something and so far I was able to show that there exists a $p\in[0,x]$ such that $p\in\bigcap\limits_{i=1}^n C(U_{\alpha_i})$, since $x\notin P$, yet I don't know where to go from there.

Thanks for any hints to this problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's assume otherwise for a contradiction. We'll prove $x\in P$. Of course, there's an element $U_x$ in the cover containing $x$. $U_x$ must contain a point $p\in P$. The set $[0,p]$ admits a finite subcovering by the given open cover and together with $U_x$, we have an finite subcovering of $[0,x]$. In other words, $x\in P$ which is a contradiction.

The proof is straightforward once you use all the hypothesis (e.g., the definition of $P$ which you seem to have forgotten to use in your proof).

***Exercise 1***: We've proved that $P$ is closed. Can you use a similar argument to prove that $P$ is open in $[0,1]$?

***Exercise 2***: Use the connectedness of $[0,1]$ to deduce the compactness of $[0,1]$.

***Exercise 3***: In order to complete the proof of the compactness of $[0,1]$, we need to establish the connectedness of $[0,1]$. Let $\{U,V\}$ constitute a non-trivial separation of $[0,1]$. Let's assume without loss of generality that $0\in U$. Prove that the least upper bound of $U$ is an element of $U\cap V$; a contradiction. Therefore, $[0,1]$ is connected.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Yes, that was great. I was thinking contradiction as well and realized that $x\in\bar{P}$, but I didn't think about adjoining the coverings like you did. Thanks for the help!

Comment: The next part of this problem is to show that $P=[0,1]$ and hence compact. Let me see where I get in figuring that out.

Comment: OK, sure @ShantDanielian. I've added some relevant exercises but there are other (more direct) ways of proving that $P=[0,1]$. Good luck!

Comment: Would showing that $P=[0,1]$ just be that since $[0,1]$ is connected with $P$ open and closed and $P\subset[0,1]$, that $P$ must be $[0,1]$. And since there's a finite subcovering for $P$ there's one for $[0,1]$ and so that means $[0,1]$ is compact.

Comment: Forgot to mention that I've already established that the only connected subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ are intervals.

Comment: Yes, you're right @ShantDanielian but you still need to prove that $P$ is open relative to $[0,1]$ (***Exercise 1***). If you know how to do that, then you're done!

Comment: Sounds good. Thanks for all the help Amitesh.